# Change Datacontext of a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have to work with a UserControl, that I cannot change. The Datacontext of this UserControl is set to itself in its constructor.

```
public ParameterControl()
{
    Datacontext = this;
}
```

The UserControl should be the template of my ListBox-Items.

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <parameterControl:ParameterControl
            DataContext="{Binding ElementName=StepView, Path=Datacontext.SelectedStep}" //this doesn't work
         </parameterControl:ParameterControl>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My implemented binding for the datacontext doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem or tell me at what point of time the datacontexts are set?

Thanks for help,
Alex

**EDIT:**

Hi again,

there is no chance to rebuild the ParameterControl.
I've got this idea...

```
<ListBox
   ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}"
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <parameterControl:ParameterControl
            ParamName="{Binding <!--To the item in the ItemsSource-Collection-->}"
         </parameterControl:ParameterControl>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The parameter Control needs only the name for the ParamName property to be displayed correctly.
And this name is in the item of the ItemsSource-Collection.

Do anyone now how to bind?

Thanks for help, Alex

Comment: the way that the user control has been created is incorrect, as such any suggestion we could provided would have to be based on the incorrect set up of the user control which we can't provide with out knowing more about it, DataContext should default to parent.DataContext, unless overridden

Comment: `Path=Datacontext.SelectedStep`: it should be `DataContext`. is it a typo in the question or in real code? does binding work if you don't use `ParameterControl` in datatemplate? try replace it with smth simple (e.g. Label) and test binding

Comment: A UserControl that is used in the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl must not explicitly set its DataContext, because doing so prevents inheriting the DataContext from the item container (e.g. the ListBoxItem here).

Comment: @ASh: Datacontext was only a typo.

Answer (score 1):

A UserControl that is used in the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl must not explicitly set its `DataContext` property, because doing so prevents inheriting the DataContext from the item container (e.g. the ListBoxItem here).

The only valid solution for this problem is to remove the DataContext assignment from the UserControl's constructor, and to replace any possible "internal" DataContext-based bindings by `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` bindings, like

```
<TextBlock
    Text="{Binding SomeText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

where `SomeText` is a property of the UserControl class.

As a general rule, never set the `DataContext` property of a UserControl explicitly.

Comment: Ok Clemens, I'm going to tell it to my colleagues, because you are right. this is also my opinion :)

Comment: @Alex Don't tell them this unless they fight hard to keep doing it wrong, but If they absolutely insist on setting a DataContext to `this`, they can give the outermost `Grid` a name `x:Name="contextElement"`, set `contextElement.DataContext = this;`, and then write a lot of horrible kludge code to work around that. I did that a few times when I was clueless about WPF. Not *quite* as monstrous as what they're doing now.