# WPF binding user-control in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I am struggling to bind my user-defined tooltip to the items of a `TreeView`.
This is the XAML inside the `TreeView`: as you can see I bind my `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to the `GroupWrapper` (simple Class that exposes the properties Name and Children) and the `DataTemplate` to the `DocWrapper` (again, simple Class that has properties such as Name, Icon, BsonContent).

```
<TreeView.Resources>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tmistruct:GroupWrapper}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tmistruct:DocWrapper}" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding BsonContent}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewTextboxItemStyle}"/>
        <StackPanel.ToolTip>
            <local:MyDocTooltip   
                NameField="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackPanel.ToolTip>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

It all works great! The Tree is automatically populated with the correct text and icons for all nodes BUT... my user-defined tooltip doesn't get the memo. **The tooltip shows**, but the name field is not populated. Note that if I replace

```
<local:MyDocTooltip
    NameField="{Binding Name}"/>
```

with:

```
<local:MyDocTooltip   
    NameField="TESTSTRING"/>
```

The test string is correctly displayed in the Tooltip.

This is what my user-defined tooltip looks like:

```
namespace MyControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MyDocTooltip.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyDocTooltip : UserControl
    {
        public MyDocTooltip()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NameFieldProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NameField", typeof(string), typeof(MyDocTooltip));
        public string NameField
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(NameFieldProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NameFieldProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess something to do with my tooltip's data context being set to its own ViewModel? I've been trying with relative references but with no luck. Any help appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39979737/1506454

Comment: @ASh thanks, that link is very useful. It confirms what I have figured out after hours of research: that I have to avoid setting the DataContext of the control, and point it to its ancestor. But I haven't figured out how to make it work yet :(

Comment: Thanks @ASh but I don't think that would help. The user-defined tooltip is inside another user-defined control, where I also set DataContext=this... so I guess I have to re-think my understanding of the MVVM. I am self-taught, it shows.

Answer (score 0):

OK my whole setup was wrong. (Thanks @ASh)
For those out there who are struggling with similar issues:

Each user control should **not** set its `DataContext` property!
This should be inherited.
What you do inside each user control, is to bind each element to its `UserControl` ancestor.
So, inside `MyDocTooltip.xaml` each element will be defined like this (bound to `NameField` property):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=NameField}"/>
```

Then I do the same in the TreeView (which is also inside a user control):

```
    <TreeView x:Name="treeViewCollection" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=FilteredGroups, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tmistruct:GroupWrapper}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="TreeViewDataTemplate"  DataType="{x:Type tmistruct:DocWrapper}" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding BsonContent}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <StackPanel.ToolTip>
                        <local:MyDocTooltip                             
                            NameField="{Binding Name}"
                            />
                    </StackPanel.ToolTip>                        
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

And it all seems to work fine. Please do let me know if I'm still doing it wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: By the way, am I breaking any policies by answering my own question? I am not accepting my own answer or it would look like I did it on purpose to gain reputation. Not sure what is the accepted behavior in these cases.