# Binding inside XAML UserControl template body

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a `UserControl` that I'm using to create a simple CardView like you would find in the DevExpress toolkit.  It consists of just a header and a body.  The body is a `<ContentPresenter/>` that binds to the control's `Body` dependency property.

Here is the XAML for the `UserControl`

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TwinAxis.UI.WPF.Controls.CardControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TwinAxis.UI.WPF.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="SensorStateLabelStyle">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="CardHeader" TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="35" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Border BorderBrush="DarkSlateGray" BorderThickness="1" Background="White">
            <Border.BitmapEffect>
                <DropShadowBitmapEffect Color="{StaticResource WindowsMediaMainColor}"
                                        ShadowDepth="3"
                                        Direction="315"
                                        Softness="0.45"
                                        Opacity="0.75"/>
            </Border.BitmapEffect>
        </Border>

        <Border>
            <DockPanel>
                <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{StaticResource CardHeader}">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderText}"
                               DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                               Padding="5"
                               Text="{Binding Header}" />
                </Border>
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                              Padding="5"
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Body}" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The CardControl.xaml.cs code behind

```cs
public partial class CardControl : UserControl {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BodyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Body), typeof(object), typeof(CardControl), new PropertyMetadata());

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Header), typeof(string), typeof(CardControl), new PropertyMetadata());

    public CardControl() {
        InitializeComponent();
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
    }

    public object Body {
        get => GetValue(BodyProperty);
        set => SetValue(BodyProperty, value);
    }

    public string Header {
        get => (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty);
        set => SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
    }

}
```

If I use it like below it works perfectly fine

```xml
<!-- Works -->
<ctrl:CardControl Header="Test">
    <ctrl:CardControl.Body>
        <Grid><!-- XAML inside grid --></Grid>
    </ctrl:CardControl.Body>
</ctrl:CardControl>
<!-- Nothing in the body even though I have data templates setup properly -->
<ctrl:CardControl Header="Test">
    <ctrl:CardControl.Body>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MachineViewModel}" />
    </ctrl:CardControl.Body>
</ctrl:CardControl>
```

What am I doing wrong?
[image: Output]

Comment: Shouldn't that be `<ctrl:CardControl Header="Test" Body="{Binding MachineViewModel}"/>`? You might also want to use the UserControl's ContentTemplate in addition to the Body property. Even better, drop the Body property and use the UserControl's Content. You would then move its current XAML (which is by default its Content) into a Style.

Comment: I moved the current XAML into a Style that sets the control's template property.  So now `<ctrl:CardControl Header="Test"><ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}"/></ctrl:CardControl` now works.  I've noticed though that I can set `CardControl`'s Margin property and get desired result.  If I try to set every card control's Margin property through a Style on the page I'm using it the style doesn't apply.  Would that be a separate SO question?

Comment: `LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;` - well, you forced isolated dataContext for userControl, so you can forget about *any* external binding like `Content="{Binding MachineViewModel}"` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25699347/1506454, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39979737/1506454

Comment: I did get rid of that concept altogether.  It came from a suggestion from a different SO question.  After reading the ones you provided it makes perfect sense.  This is what happens when somebody who isn't a UI designer has to make views for the front end.  Any idea on the issue with setting style properties or should that be a separate question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Clemens and @ASh in the comments I was able to fix the issue by moving all of that "template" code where it belongs in a `<Style />` tag for the UserControl's `Template` property.  I also removed the forced isolated `DataContext` that was mentioned in the comments and I'm now able to fill out the content of the CardControl and have it render like I wanted.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TwinAxis.UI.WPF.Controls.CardControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TwinAxis.UI.WPF.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="SensorStateLabelStyle">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="CardHeader" TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="35" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="local:CardControl">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CardControl">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border BorderBrush="DarkSlateGray" BorderThickness="1" Background="White">
                                <Border.BitmapEffect>
                                    <DropShadowBitmapEffect Color="{StaticResource WindowsMediaMainColor}"
                                                            ShadowDepth="3"
                                                            Direction="315"
                                                            Softness="0.45"
                                                            Opacity="0.75"/>
                                </Border.BitmapEffect>
                            </Border>

                            <Border>
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{StaticResource CardHeader}">
                                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderText}"
                                                   DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                                   Padding="5"
                                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
                                    </Border>
                                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                                  Padding="5"
                                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```